# Get the error from Fragment with different activities when passing data using bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am using Bundle to passing data from my `MainActivity` to `Fragment` but it prompts out with the JAVA.NULLPOINTER.EXCEPTION`. Error is occur when I`getArguments()` in list_fragments2 in second activity

**MainActivity**

```
list_fragment2 fragment = new list_fragment2();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("test","text");
fragment.setArguments(b);
Toast.makeText(this, "" + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**list_fragment2**

```
String name = getArguments().getString("test");
ntab2.setText(name);
```

**Logcat**

```
01-02 07:19:52.549 15797-15797/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.Tab2.list_fragment2.onCreateView(list_fragment2.java:62)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1983)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:926)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1272)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1630)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
```

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: but i got create a value for my bundle

Comment: String name = getArguments().getString("test");<------ this line

Comment: first fragment :

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

second fragment : 

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}

Comment: thanks, i try this before, but my second fragment still return with value null

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution you have to change a little code in list_fragment2
First you have to make bundle and then get String like

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
    String name = bundle.getString("test");
    ntab2.setText(name);
  }
```

Problem solve.

Comment: thanks  you, but i still cant get the value from activity

Answer (score 0):

change this line of your code.

> String name = getArguments().getString("test");

to

> String name = this.getArguments().getString("test");

it will work.

Comment: thanks you , i still get same error

Answer (score 0):

On your second fragment use like this

call getArguments() in your List_fragment2's onCreateView() metod:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup containerObject,
         Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //here is your arguments
         Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

        //your string
        String test=bundle.getString("test");   
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it didnt work for me

Comment: is your fragment name Tab2? then change to
`Tab2 fragment = new Tab2();`

Comment: nope, my bundle in list_fragment2 still return with value null